# rails forms updating a db record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, formtastic

I would like to rewrite a form which is used to update a record on a database.
I want to update the form so that the form input does not show the record, as
the record is outputted by the line

```
<%= q.object.content %>.
```

I want the
form input not to display the record, and I want that the record is updated
when the input field is edited, and is not edited when it is left blank.

I am new at working with forms and don't know the best way to achieve this.

Can anyone provide any help on achieving this ? Below is the current form. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<%= semantic_form_for @bunchOfThings do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs do %>
        <%= f.semantic_fields_for :aThing, @aThing do |q| %>
            <%= q.object.content %> 
            <%= q.input :content, label: "A Thing: #{q.object.content}" %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.action :submit , label: t('Some Text'), button_html: { class: 'btn btn-primary' } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you considered using `form_tags`? this will not be bounded to any object, so it won't show it. then, you can then manually bind the params to the object in your update method of the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually set the default value of a field to an empty string by changing this line:

```
<%= q.input :content, label: "A Thing: #{q.object.content}" %>
```

To this:

```
<%= q.input :content, label: "A Thing: #{q.object.content}", input_html: {value:''} %>
```

You would also need to filter out blank fields on the backend within the update controller method.  Something like this:

```
def update
  filtered_params = permitted_record_params
  filtered_params.keep_if{|k,v| !v.blank? }
  record.update(filtered_params)
  ...
end
```

Where of course the `permitted_record_params` method returns your permitted params hash.

Comment: Thanks Joeman29. Your suggestion helped get me over the line. I had to modify it a bit, and use byebug to see what was happening, but your answer helped a lot.